# Strange results when adding two variables in MS Access VBA that equal Zero

Tags: vba, variables, ms-access

I have a routine in my VBA MSAccess platform that has me baffled.
All I am doing is summing up an amount field as I loop through a recordset.

I have declared a variable called TempAmount (which holds the totals as we loop through).
The field name in the table is called BilledAmount in a records set called rsBilled.

As the loop begins, TempAmount is at Zero.  As the loop progresses, we add the BilledAmount to the TempAmount.

Here is a mockup of the code.

```
Dim TempAmount as Double
TempAmount = 0


While NOT rsBilled.EOF
   TempAmount = TempAmount + rsBilled.Fields("BilledAmount")

rsBilled.MoveNext

Wend
```

(Then we go and write TempAmount to another table that houses Totals.)

Now THIS ALL WORKS FINE.  EXCEPT when TempAmount and BilledAmount are in opposite amounts which produce a Zero.
In other words, if TempAmount is 15.25 and BilledAmount = -15.25, the result should be zero.   But that doesnt happen.  Instead, I get some wild expanded notation value like 2.123423523E-10.

Again, this ONLY happens when the result will equal a zero because of a postive value being added to the opposite negative value.

Any clues?

Answer (score 3):

You have declared `TempAmount` as a `double`, so you're dealing with floating-point numbers, and not fixed-point numbers.

Declare `TempAmount` as a `currency` instead.

Comment: Absolutely. And it is sometimes best to use format to round up before writing currency, if you want to keep accounts happy.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim TempAmount as Double 
TempAmount = 0

While NOT rsBilled.EOF 
TempAmount = Round(TempAmount,4) + Round(rsBilled.Fields("BilledAmount"),4)
rsBilled.MoveNext
Wend
```